# Logstash 6.2.3 Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm getting this warning when i start my logstash with the given below config.
if type has been removed then how to map multiple jdbc inputs to seaparate indices called "agency" and  "subscriber". how to define output to elastic search.

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname"
jdbc_user => "XXXX"
jdbc_password => "XXXX"
jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
jdbc_fetch_size  => 500
lowercase_column_names => "false"
schedule => "* * * * * *"
last_run_metadata_path => "\RunConfig\logpos\agency_last_run"
statement_filepath => "\RunConfig\sql\agency.sql"
type => "agencydetails"

 }

 jdbc {
  type => "subscriberdetails"
  jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar"
  jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname"
  jdbc_user => "XXXX"
  jdbc_password => "XXXX"
  jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
  jdbc_fetch_size  => 500
  lowercase_column_names => "false"
  schedule => "* * * * * *"
  last_run_metadata_path => "RunConfig\logpos\subscriber_last_run"
   statement_filepath => "\RunConfig\sql\subscriber.sql"
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two separate file configurations for defining two pipelines: each pipeline will fetch from only one input JDBC, inserting in the defined index: in this case, you will need of two instances running of logstash.

Otherwise, you can use also one instance, using if then else to route the data in the preferred index:

```
output
{
   if [type] == "agencydetails"
   {
     elasticsearch
     {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        user => "xxx"
        password => "xxx"
        index => "agencydetails"    
     }
   }
   else
   {
      elasticsearch
      {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        user => "xxx"
        password => "xxx"
        index => "subscriberdetails"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: "type" has been defaulted to "doc" in index mapping of 6.2 elastic search version and in feature versions it will be deprecated.
that was my concern.
Below is the link which explains removal.
[Details link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/removal-of-types.html)

if so how it will be managed in logstash jdbc plugin